# Methods on numpy recarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy recarray and want to calculate some statistics. I don't want to use `pandas` but am looking for a solution using recarray (if there is one).

Is there a way to e.g. calculate the `mean` of both "columns" without "unwrapping" the "columns" first?

The below throws `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`.

```
x = np.array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)], dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i8')])
x = x.view(np.recarray)

x.mean() # Error
```

I could only come up with the below solution.

```
means = [np.mean(x[rec])for rec in x.dtype.names]
```

Is there an easier fix?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, but I want to conduct statistics on each `column` which only contain elements of the same type. In this case one column is float and one is integer. Still no way?

Comment: What's wrong with the loop? The operation cannot be vectorized across columns with disparate types anyway. A record array is handled and stored fundamentally different to an ndarray. You can think of it as a vector of structs. Maybe pandas will calculate the column-wise mean without complaining.

Comment: You would need same dtype per columns to achieve what you need I guess.

Comment: You need an iterative solution. You can't apply directly (in a vectorized way) along some axis having mixed types @FredMaster

Comment: If you have a very large array, you're probably better off having two separate arrays by dtype, and using numpys functions separately

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will use a different solution then - which is no problem. Was just curious if a solution exists.

Comment: Typically a structured array has many more records than fields, so iterating over the desired fields shouldn't be much of a time issue.  In addition the fields include strings that don't implement math.  Structured arrays are most useful as an interface to `csv` files.  And for more complex analysis, it may be worth switching to `pandas`.